# Twitter widget not compatible with WordPress 3.7

Tags: wordpress, twitter, widget, compatibility, twitter-widget

I try to install twitter widget on WordPress 3.7 but its crashed :(

So help me, or suggest if there is any alternate twitter widget which is  compatible with WordPress 3.7?

[Twitter Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter/)

Comment: May be you should upgrade WordPress. Latest version is 4.2.2. According to the plugin `Requires: 3.9 or higher`.

Comment: i cant update wordpress, can u other solution?

Comment: Plugin author is not supporting before WP 3.9. If you cant upgrade WP then you should search for other plugin with similar feature.

Comment: u you know other twiter plugin  with similar feature?